# Create deep copy of List<object>

Tags: c#, .net, list, copy

I read a lot of articles where people describes how to create a deep copy of list. But it requires a lot of code or work with memory streams. Is there any other easier way to create independent copy of List of class objects?

Comment: Either you have to implement IClonable interface youself for all the objects you want to clone or you have to work with memory streams (serialization etc.).   There's no other way I think

Comment: Or just use immutable types and then you don't need to clone it at all. ;)